# How to enable safari browser caching for urls which are 302 redirects

Tags: safari, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache, http-status-code-302

I have a single-page application which is dependent on a javascript bundle to work. For fetching this bundle's CDN (cloudfront) url, I'm making a call to an AWS API Gateway endpoint which returns a HTTP 302 response having the Location header parameter as the CDN url. Now this CDN Url responds with cache-control headers having a sufficiently large max-age value. All the other browsers like Chrome, Firefox seem to honor this and cache the CDN Url response for further requests. But Safari isn't doing so (Version - 12). However, it does cache the response when I'm making the request to the CDN Url directly. Do I need to add some more headers or some additional metadata in the 302 response to make it work for safari?

I tried fiddling with the cache-control parameters like adding 'immutable' but nothing worked. I googled quite a lot about this issue but nothing concrete turned up.

I expected Safari to work with just the max-age parameter present in CDN's response, but it never caches it.

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77538 describes your problem. Set cache-control header to no-store in api-gateway response.

Comment: no-store would cause it to always make a call to the API gateway endpoint and nothing else, it would not affect the behavior for cloud front calls. What i want is for safari to just cache the CDN url's response.

Comment: Last comment in webkit bug "CachedRawResource now keeps the redirect chain, and has some trivial logic for checking correctness, but it's nowhere near complete (only checks cacheControlContainsNoStore()). And of course other resource types don't have anything." explains why 302 redirect chain (in you case to CDN) will be cached in safari when cacheControlContainsNoStore

Comment: I gave this a shot. It still doesn't work

Comment: Filed a formal bug on Apple's bug reporter for this since it was reproducible by others for their pages as well

Comment: Ankur, do you have a reference/link to the bug report? We're seeing exact same symptom and would like to have something to track/monitor.

Comment: As near as we can see - Safari looks to be using the cache lifetime of the 30x as the cache lifetime of the subsequent resource retrieval. (Which makes me wonder if it would also ignore a _shorter_ lifetime on the CDN-retrieved resource if your redirect had a long lifetime)

Comment: @NathanNeulinger We have also drilled down the issue to that only. Problem is we don't want to cache the 302 response itself since that beats the whole purpose of having a cached redirect only. Here's the [bug reference](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=47729784). Let me know if you guys find something out

Comment: @AnkurMishra The bug reference cannot be opened unless I am part of a beta program apparently. Can you update us on the status of it?